# Plot timelines of different data sets in order to identify (non) overlaps

Tags: excel, vba

I have two data sets:

Data set 1: It is a 10min resolution and it is a binary flag indicating "System OK" or "System not OK". For example:

*01/01/2018 12:10-12:20 System not OK*

Data set 2: This is the fault log with hh:mm:ss timestamps indicating the start-end times of a fault. For example:

*Active Fault code X: 01/01/2018 12:08:23-12:19:14*

Ideally, for every time span indicated as "System not OK" there must be a fault logging covering part of that 10min period. However, there are inconsistencies in both ends; either I see "System not OK" but no Fault covering that 10min period or there is a fault but "System OK".

What I would like to achieve is to filter the 10min timespans where there is an inconsistency of either kind (and ideally flag it as "System OK but active fault" or "System not OK but no active fault).

Do you think that would be possible in Excel or VBA?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Fault Log
1 Dec 13:47 - 1 Dec 13:48
1 Dec 16:44 - 1 Dec 16:45
1 Dec 19:47 - 1 Dec 19:47
1 Dec 20:23 - 1 Dec 21:08
1 Dec 21:08 - 1 Dec 21:08
1 Dec 21:43 - 2 Dec 01:44
2 Dec 01:44 - 2 Dec 01:45
3 Dec 14:52 - 3 Dec 16:28
3 Dec 16:52 - 3 Dec 17:10
3 Dec 17:34 - 3 Dec 17:36
4 Dec 00:48 - 4 Dec 00:49
4 Dec 02:06 - 4 Dec 02:07
4 Dec 04:59 - 4 Dec 04:59
4 Dec 06:47 - 4 Dec 06:48
6 Dec 09:34 - 6 Dec 09:35
6 Dec 09:39 - 6 Dec 14:16
6 Dec 14:19 - 6 Dec 14:19
6 Dec 14:19 - 6 Dec 14:20

System Ok log
12/1/2018 12:00 OK
12/1/2018 12:10 NOK
12/1/2018 12:20 OK
12/1/2018 12:30 OK
12/1/2018 12:40 OK
12/1/2018 12:50 OK
12/1/2018 13:00 OK
12/1/2018 13:10 OK
12/1/2018 13:20 OK
12/1/2018 13:30 OK
12/1/2018 13:40 NOK
12/1/2018 13:50 OK
12/1/2018 14:00 OK
12/1/2018 14:10 OK
12/1/2018 14:20 OK
12/1/2018 14:30 OK
12/1/2018 14:40 OK
12/1/2018 14:50 OK
12/1/2018 15:00 OK
12/1/2018 15:10 OK
12/1/2018 15:20 OK
12/1/2018 15:30 OK
12/1/2018 15:40 OK
12/1/2018 15:50 OK
12/1/2018 16:00 OK
12/1/2018 16:10 OK
12/1/2018 16:20 OK
12/1/2018 16:30 OK
12/1/2018 16:40 OK
12/1/2018 16:50 OK
12/1/2018 17:00 OK
12/1/2018 17:10 OK

Desired outcome:

Evaluation
12/1/2018 12:00
12/1/2018 12:10 system NOK but no fault
12/1/2018 12:20
12/1/2018 12:30
12/1/2018 12:40
12/1/2018 12:50
12/1/2018 13:00
12/1/2018 13:10
12/1/2018 13:20
12/1/2018 13:30
12/1/2018 13:40
12/1/2018 13:50
12/1/2018 14:00
12/1/2018 14:10
12/1/2018 14:20
12/1/2018 14:30
12/1/2018 14:40
12/1/2018 14:50
12/1/2018 15:00
12/1/2018 15:10
12/1/2018 15:20
12/1/2018 15:30
12/1/2018 15:40
12/1/2018 15:50
12/1/2018 16:00
12/1/2018 16:10
12/1/2018 16:20
12/1/2018 16:30
12/1/2018 16:40 system OK but fault
12/1/2018 16:50
12/1/2018 17:00
12/1/2018 17:10

Comment: Please post a sample of the data as it would appear on an Excel spreadsheet, with column headers and also the desired output.

Comment: @M.R. Thanks for your reply! I have added the example on the bottom of the comment. Would that suffice? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, give me a couple of hours and I'll have look into this.

Comment: @M.R. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I am thinking of a method to do this using SQL (you can use SQL against an Excel table), just trying to figure out the right query

Answer (score 0):

I am posting an idea that may be helpful for you to try doing this. Sorry, I did not tested it, this is only a starting point.
First add a reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1" first. Then try the macro. 
Basically you can filter out those records from TableA (that is on Sheet1) whose datetime values do not fall into any range in TableB (that is on Sheet2)

TableA is Sheet1 that has in first row (the header) **TimeOk**. Next rows have the data.

```
  TimeOK 
  12/1/2018 12:00
```

TableB is Sheet2 that has in first row (the headers) **FromTime** and **ToTime**. Next rows have the data

```
  FromTime               ToTime
  12/1/2018 13:47        12/1/2018 13:48
```

Set cell type as dates and format then nicely as datetime in a consistent mode on both sheets. Do not use different date formats as in the data yuu posted.

The macro should write the result on Sheet3 (make sure you add it)

```
Sub GetSpecialRecords()

 Dim sQuery As String, sFileName  as String
 Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
 Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

 sFileName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
 sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""" & _
   sFileName & """;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX = 1"""

 Conn.Open sConnection 
 sQuery = "SELECT t1.[TimeOk] From [Sheet1$] t1 INNER JOIN [Sheet2$] t2 ON t1.[TimeOk]>= t2.FromTime AND t1.[TimeOk] <= t2.[ToTime]"
  rs.Open sQuery , Conn

 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
 rs.Close
 conn.Close

End Sub
```

As I said, start with this, you need a little SQL language knowledge though in order to solve the problem...